# Are questions of the type "What *product* is this?" allowed?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Often times, one finds resources, plugins, scripts or libraries on websites that one would like to identify. For example, would a question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ like this be acceptable?

"I found this gallery on this website: *website here*. Can anyone tell me what plugin this is?"

Comment: Most sites consider "identify-this" style questions to be off-topic. We can't answer your question here, because the answer is on a per-site basis. For the policies specific to Wordpress SE, you'd need to visit [Meta Wordpress](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com). Though I doubt they would consider that question on-topic.

Comment: That actually clears things up. Thank you.

Comment: This question does not pertain to a specific site. **As stated in the question**, that was an example. Honestly, sometimes the Stack Exchange moderators just crack me up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, no. Some sites have policies specifically preventing this. For example, from the [Stack Overflow help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

However, some sites actually have tags meant for this. For example, [Scifi's story-identification tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification):

> Questions asking for help identifying a TV series/episode, comic-book issue/story arc, movie, book, or other story.

These are typically off-topic, however. They're

- often "link-only questions," meaning if the page you are linking to is changed or moved then the question becomes worthless. This can sometimes be mitigated via, for example, a screenshot.
- sometimes Too Broad, because the same effect can be achieved many different ways.
- likely to attract spam (use my plugin! it does this and it's only $1999!).
- also likely to attract link-only answers.